# Appending to NSMutableString in a for loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

```
NSMutableString*  highlightedString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:1];
for (QWZTerm* term in self.highlightArray) {
    [highlightedString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@ ", term.value];
}
```

Basically term.values are NSStrings ( "john" and "mary" and I would like to append them like "john mary". Unfortunately above doesn't work for me. I would appreciate any directions.

Comment: FYI - why do you create the mutable string with an initial capacity of only 1? Why not something like `self.highlightArray.count * x` where `x` is a rough guess as to the average size of the term values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using a wrong method: `stringByAppendingFormat:` works on all strings, mutable and immutable, because it *returns* a new `NSString` object.

Since you are looking to change the content of mutable `highlightedString` itself, you need to use `appendFormat:` instead:

```
NSMutableString*  highlightedString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:1];
for (QWZTerm* term in self.highlightArray) {
    [highlightedString appendFormat:@"%@ ", term.value];
}
```

You could do the whole thing without using mutable strings or loops, in a single line of code:

```
NSString* res = [[highlightArray valueForKey:@"value"] componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

The "magic" behind the `valueForKey` call is described [here](http://iosdevtips.co/post/80598241763/valueforkey-nsarray).

Comment: you win! thanks a lot for even better solution and link!

Answer (score 2):

A different solution would be to gather the strings in a mutable array and then join them:

```
NSMutableArray* values = [NSMutableArray array];
for (QWZTerm* term in self.highlightArray) {
    [values addObject:term.value];
}

NSString* highlightedString = [values componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

This avoids the trailing space you'll get with the `appenFormat:` solution.

Comment: @ilteris You haven't accept any answer. And even if you do, you can change it.

Comment: You are correct, I just voted it up. I mixed it up with accepting it. I apologize. @darkdust, can you elaborate on the trailing space issue please?

Comment: @ilteris: When you always append a format `@"%@ "` you will always have a space at the end of the result string (from the format). That may be unwanted. With `componentsJoinedByString:`, there is no additional space at the end, only spaces between the elements.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is wrong. Use `appendFormat:`. `stringByAppendingFormat:` returns a new NSString object and does not append to there NSMutableString instance.

```
NSMutableString*  highlightedString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:1];
for (QWZTerm* term in self.highlightArray) {
    [highlightedString appendFormat:@"%@ ", term.value];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also change the line

```
[highlightedString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@ ", term.value];
```

to

```
highLightedString = [highlightedString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@ ", term.value];
```

Comment: … which would assign a `NSString` to a `NSMutableString` variable and also waste memory since for every iteration a new string will be allocated. Not a good solution.